# Implements live highcharts in ionic 2

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic2, livecharts

I want to implement a live chart : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update/sand-signika in ionic 2, so angular2

I had tried many times, but always I got wrong.

I saw this code in js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

But it gives me errors on Highcharts. Also on $(document(.ready()) but i just remove it and it works, so the problem is Highcharts.

Im woring in typescript so also the synthax is different. 
Also I saw this : [here](https://github.com/Bigous/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts/) but no idea how to implement.

My purpose is to achive a realtime line chart in ionic 2.

Comment: You have not pasted the code here or create an example of the issue - the code you've pasted is fine. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to recreate a live example of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Highcharts in Angular2 you can do it via
[Angular2 HighCharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts) that provides the correct bindings.

The instructions worked fine for me:

From CL:
    `npm install angular2-highcharts --save`

In your `App.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { App } from './App';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')
    ],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```